# Relative Pointer Position

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I need some help figuring out how to calculate the relative pointer position on a [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com) stage.

In my case my stage changes [position](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#setPosition), [offset](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#setOffset), and [scale](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#setScale).

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pCZzv/

```
function getRelativePointerPosition() {
    var pointer = stage.getPointerPosition();
    var pos = stage.getPosition();
    var offset = stage.getOffset();
    var scale = stage.getScale();

    return {
        x : ((pointer.x - pos.x + offset.x) / scale.x),
        y : ((pointer.y - pos.y + offset.y) / scale.y)
    };
}
```

I want the red circles to appear where the mouse is clicked. 
I'm running into problems when the stage has changed it's offset and scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculation of the `x` and `y` coordinates are slightly off. This is a working demo of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/pCZzv/1/

Here is the relevant changed code:

```
function getRelativePointerPosition() {
    var pointer = stage.getPointerPosition();
    var pos = stage.getPosition();
    var offset = stage.getOffset();
    var scale = stage.getScale();

    return {
        x : ((pointer.x / scale.x) - (pos.x / scale.x) + offset.x),
        y : ((pointer.y / scale.y) - (pos.y / scale.y) + offset.y)
    };
}
```